# How can I create a transparent shape within an existing shape using KineticJS

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Is there a simple way to "stamp" a transparent section from within another shape (or layer) using KineticJS?

For example, using the following code:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'canvas',
    width: 100,
    height: 100
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 1,
    y: 1,
    width: 96,
    height: 96,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2
});

layer.add(rect);

var star = new Kinetic.Star({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    numPoints: 5,
    innerRadius: 15,
    outerRadius: 40,
    fill: 'yellow'
});

layer.add(star);

stage.add(layer);
```

How would I make the star shape within the green box transparent so that elements behind the canvas are visible. Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPVxa/

I have looked into filters, and I think that may be the way to go, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use a Kinetic Shape Object to do custom drawing, including your star cut-out**

The Shape gives you access to a context which gives you access to the full range of canvas operations.

The operation needed for “cutting” your star from your background is globalCompositeOperation.

The “destination-out” composite will cut out the next drawn shape (your star) from any existing drawings (your green rect).

Here is how you draw the green rect and use composition to cut out the star.

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Shape({
    drawFunc: function(canvas){
        context=canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.save();
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(0,0,96,96);
        context.fillStyle="green";
        context.fill();
        context.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
        drawStar(context,45,50,5,40,15);
        canvas.fillStroke(this);
        context.restore();
    },
    width: 96,
    height: 96,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2
});
```

Since the star is not a native canvas shape, you will also need this code to draw a star:

```
function drawStar(ctx,cx,cy,spikes,outerRadius,innerRadius){
  var rot=Math.PI/2*3;
  var x=cx;
  var y=cy;
  var step=Math.PI/spikes;

  ctx.strokeSyle="#000";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(cx,cy-outerRadius)
  for(i=0;i<spikes;i++){
    x=cx+Math.cos(rot)*outerRadius;
    y=cy+Math.sin(rot)*outerRadius;
    ctx.lineTo(x,y)
    rot+=step

    x=cx+Math.cos(rot)*innerRadius;
    y=cy+Math.sin(rot)*innerRadius;
    ctx.lineTo(x,y)
    rot+=step
  }
  ctx.lineTo(cx,cy-outerRadius)
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}
```

That’s pretty much it!

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/VVrZT/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.3.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer">
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 300,
        height: 300
      });
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      stage.add(layer);

      var rect = new Kinetic.Shape({
          drawFunc: function(canvas){
              context=canvas.getContext("2d");
              context.save();
              context.beginPath();
              context.rect(0,0,96,96);
              context.fillStyle="green";
              context.fill();
              context.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
              drawStar(context,45,50,5,40,15);
              canvas.fillStroke(this);
              context.restore();
          },
          width: 96,
          height: 96,
          fill: 'green',
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 2
      });
      layer.add(rect);
      layer.draw();


      function drawStar(ctx,cx,cy,spikes,outerRadius,innerRadius){
        var rot=Math.PI/2*3;
        var x=cx;
        var y=cy;
        var step=Math.PI/spikes;

        ctx.strokeSyle="#000";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(cx,cy-outerRadius)
        for(i=0;i<spikes;i++){
          x=cx+Math.cos(rot)*outerRadius;
          y=cy+Math.sin(rot)*outerRadius;
          ctx.lineTo(x,y)
          rot+=step

          x=cx+Math.cos(rot)*innerRadius;
          y=cy+Math.sin(rot)*innerRadius;
          ctx.lineTo(x,y)
          rot+=step
        }
        ctx.lineTo(cx,cy-outerRadius)
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: globalCompositeOperation was what I was looking for. For my use, the ideal solution would allow a composite of two KineticJS shape objects (i.e. Kinetic.Rect and Kinetic.Star) just for ease of coding, but this answers my posted question, so I'll accept it.